# problem to make connection for send sms in j2me

Tags: java-me, sms, sendmessage

Hi
i try to make a connection with this code but this error shown :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid port format

```
MessageConnection messageConnection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://09364191752");
```

wath is wrong ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a port number at the end of the phone number, i.e. append ":5000" or whatever.

See http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wma/ for details.